# JavaScript - Is filtering '<' good enough to secure HTML before displaying?

Tags: javascript, security, html-injections

In JavaScript, is there any known string that can cause mischief if we filter out all 'less than' ('<') characters then display the result as HTML?

```
var str = GetDangerousString().toString();
var secure = str.replace(/</g, '');

$('#safe').html(secure); // or
document.getElementById('safe').innerHTML = secure;
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794137/sanitizing-user-input-before-adding-it-to-the-dom-in-javascript) addresses sanitizing ID's in particular. I'm looking for a general HTML string. Ideal answer is the simplest working example of a string that would inject code or other potentially dangerous elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sanitizing user input before adding it to the DOM in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794137/sanitizing-user-input-before-adding-it-to-the-dom-in-javascript)

Comment: Better use `textContent`

Answer (score 0):

That's not enough for sure... You need to HTML encode any HTML you embed in your pages that you want to be editable by an end user. Otherwise, you need to sanitize it.

You can find out more here at the [Owasp site](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_JavaScript_Data_Values)

EDIT: In response to your comment, I'm not 100% sure. It sounds like double encoding will get you in some cases if you're not careful.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Double_Encoding

For example, this string from that page is supposed to demonstrate an exploit that hides the "<" character:

```
%253Cscript%253Ealert('XSS')%253C%252Fscript%253E
```

Also, the character "<" can be encoded lots of different ways in HTML, as suggested by this table:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#Character_escape_sequences

So to me, that's the thing to be careful of - the fact that there may be exploitable cases that are hard to understand, but may leave you open.

But back to your original question - can you give me an example of HTML that renders as HTML that doesn't contain the "<" character? I'm trying to understand what HTML you want users to be able to use that would be in an "id".

Also, if your site is small, if you're open to rewriting parts of it (specifically how you use javascript in your pages), then you could consider using [Content Security Policies](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) to protect your users from XSS. This works in most modern browsers, and would protect lots of your users from XSS attacks if you were to take this step.

Comment: Do you have an example string?

Comment: I'm no pro on this, but have had to deal with this topic on a few sites, with multiple developers. I've edited my answer and added some info above ^^^.

Comment: Upon putting the string "%253Cscript%253Ealert('XSS')%253C%252Fscript%253E" in a website I do not see a possible bypass done, am I missing something? When all I want is to put some text from a user on a web page isn't filtering < and > enough?

Comment: @circl - I would say it's not enough - as soon as you try and write that text to the document, it may be decoded, and turn into the < and > - so you have to sanitize, or html encode. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22644385/26510) and [possibly here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41385970/26510)